# Is log4net AdoNetAppender thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, log4net

The [Log4net FAQ](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html) says that ***log4net***  is thread-safe:

> Question: Is log4net thread-safe?
>
> Answer: Yes, log4net is thread-safe.

However, the manual for the [AdoNetAppender class](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.html) says the following:

> Instance members are ***not*** guaranteed to be thread-safe.

My guess is that log4net is not thread-safe. I'm using this class to log into a database, and manually flushing the appended data from time to time. I see that some records are duplicated.

Looking at the code, it appears to me that the base class `BufferingAppenderSkeleton` locks the object for the `flush()`, however the function `SendFromBuffer()` which is eventually called can be invoked from other places without lock (for instance `Append()`). Therefore, it appears that the class is not thread-safe.

So should I conclude that the class is not thread-safe, however the usage in log4net makes it so?

Comment: How are you manually flushing the data, and do you have a buffer size set?